Parametrization of Diophantine Equation
I know you can parametrize all the rational solutions to $x^2 + y^2 = 1$ as $(x, y) = (\frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2}, \frac{2t}{1+t^2} )$ where t is rational.
The way we do this is by showing that $(x, y) = (0, -1)$ is a solution and then drawing a line with rational slope $t$ through this point.
The equation of the line is then $y = tx - 1$ where $t$ is rational.
Then, we get $$x^2 + t^2 x^2 - 2tx + 1 = 1$$ $$x^2 + t^2 x^2 = 2tx$$ $$x(1 + t^2) = 2t$$ $$x = \frac{2t}{1+t^2}$$ $$y = \frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2}$$
Is there a way to parametrize $x^2 + y^2 = 2^{m} $ where $m$ is odd?
I tried showing that $(x, y) = (2^{\frac{m-1}{2}}, 2^{\frac{m-1}{2}})$ is a solution, and that gives us the line $y = t(x - 2^{\frac{m-1}{2}}) + 2^{\frac{m-1}{2}}$ but when I expand it out, I can't figure out a way to express $x$ and $y$ in terms of $t$ alone.
Any help is appreciated.

Hint: $(x+y)^2+(x-y)^2=2^{m+1}$
